# php setTimezone different result for the same time

Tags: php

I'm getting different timezone offsets for the same time on two different machines. I cannot find root cause for that.

Testing code:

```
# create empty directory and file, so php has no configuration
mkdir /tmp/empty; touch /tmp/emptycfg
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/tmp/empty /usr/bin/php5 -c /tmp/emptycfg -r '$curTime = new \DateTime("2015-11-06 12:59:59", new \DateTimeZone("UTC")); var_dump($curTime); $curTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul")); var_dump($curTime);'
```

The result I get on one machine is:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-11-06 12:59:59.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-11-06 15:59:59.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(15) "Europe/Istanbul"
}
```

But on another:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-11-06 12:59:59.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-11-06 14:59:59.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(15) "Europe/Istanbul"
}
```

Istanbul is 3 hours ahead of UTC on November 6 (daylight changes are on Nov 8 and Mar 29).
Things I tried:

- changing system time (different months in the year)
- diff of php -i, env variables (no other changes than SSH_CLIENT, SSH_TTY, SSH_AUTH_SOCK, SSH_CONNECTION environment variables)

other info (on both machines is the same php binary (the same md5sum))

```
$ PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/tmp/empty /usr/bin/php5 -c /tmp/emptycfg -i | head -n 30
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.6.16-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1

System => Linux dev 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /tmp/emptycfg
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /tmp/empty
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20131106
PHP Extension => 20131226
Zend Extension => 220131226
Zend Extension Build => API220131226,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20131226,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => enabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that php depends on tzdata package, which received an update (changelog http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2015g-0ubuntu0.12.04/changelog).

So after doing apt-get install tzdata both machines provided the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think, 1hour difference shows towards daylight saving issue.
- Check system timezone and daylight saving settings on both computers
- Check timezone and daylight saving in php.ini on both computers

Comment: Well, system configuration really shouldn't affect the result of the function like that. If you look carefully at my testing command, I import empty configuration to the php command which is confirmed with "php -i".
I'm suspecting that the error is in DateTimeZone part. I tried different dates with Istanbul timezone and it appears that the change is different than on November 8. On the second computer the change is exactly on that date (which is expected). I'll look in php source code. Thanks for the answer.